# R: Regex madness (stringi)

Tags: r, regex, stringi

I have a vector of strings that look like this:

```
G30(H).G3(M).G0(L).Replicate(1)
```

Iterating over `c("H", "M", "L")`, I would like to extract `G30` (for "`H`"), `G3` (for "`M`") and `G0` (for "`L`").

My various attempts have me confused - the `regex101.com` debugger, e.g. indicates that `(\w*)\(M\)` works just fine, but transferring that to R fails ...

Comment: See the regex101.com attempt [here](https://regex101.com/r/cZ0sD2/66).

Comment: you've received a lot of responses! Consider accepting one (check mark to the left of answers) that you found the most helpful and most general. It lets the community know the answer worked for you and acknowledges the help you've received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `stringi` package and the `outer()` function:

```
library(stringi)

strings <- c(
  "G30(H).G3(M).G0(L).Replicate(1)",
  "G5(M).G11(L).G6(H).Replicate(9)",
  "G10(M).G6(H).G8(M).Replicate(200)"  # No "L", repeated "M"
)
targets  <- c("H", "M", "L")
patterns <- paste0("\\w+(?=\\(", targets, "\\))")
matches  <- outer(strings, patterns, FUN = stri_extract_first_regex)
colnames(matches) <- targets
matches
#      H     M    L    
# [1,] "G30" "G3" "G0" 
# [2,] "G6"  "G5" "G11"
# [3,] "G6"  "G10" NA
```

This ignores any instances of a target letter past the first, gives you an `NA` when the target's not found, and returns everything in a simple matrix. The regular expressions stored in `patterns` match substrings like `XX(Y)`, where `Y` is the target letter and `XX` is any number of word characters.

Comment: Whoa - I learned something new here! The use of `outer` is nice!

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there are better solutions, but this works...

```
jnk <- 'G30(H).G3(M).G0(L).Replicate(1)'
patter <- '([^\\(]+)\\(H\\)\\.([^\\(]+)\\(M\\)\\.([^\\(]+)\\(L\\)\\.Replicate\\(\\d+\\)'
H <- sub(patter, '\\1', jnk)
M <- sub(patter, '\\2', jnk)
L <- sub(patter, '\\3', jnk)
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, I found once a very nice function `parse.one` which makes it possible to search more in a python like regular expression way...

Have a look at this:

```
parse.one <- function(res, result) {
  m <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(res), function(i) {
    if(result[i] == -1) return("")
    st <- attr(result, "capture.start")[i, ]
    substring(res[i], st, st + attr(result, "capture.length")[i, ] - 1)
  }))
  colnames(m) <- attr(result, "capture.names")
  m
}
jnk <- 'G30(H).G3(M).G0(L).Replicate(1)'
pattern <- '(?<H>[^\\(]+)\\(H\\)\\.(?<M>[^\\(]+)\\(M\\)\\.(?<L>[^\\(]+)\\(L\\)\\.Replicate\\(\\d+\\)'
parse.one(jnk, regexpr(pattern, jnk, perl=TRUE))
```

Result looks like this:

```
> parse.one(jnk, regexpr(pattern, jnk, perl=TRUE))
     H     M    L   
[1,] "G30" "G3" "G0"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order is always the same, an alternative might be to split the strings. For instance:

```
string <- "G30(H).G3(M).G0(L).Replicate(1)"
tmp <- str_split(string, "\\.")[[1]]
lapply(tmp[1:3], function(x) str_split(x, "\\(")[[1]][1])
[[1]]
[1] "G30"

[[2]]
[1] "G3"

[[3]]
[1] "G0"
```

Answer (score 1):

If codes (e.g., 'G30') preceding the tags(e.g., '(H).') or the order of the tags in the string are allowed to change (different letters or length), you may want to try a more flexible solution based on *regexpr()*.

```
aa <-paste("G30(H).G3(M).G0(L).Replicate(",1:10,")", sep="")
my.tags <- c("H","M", "L")

extr.data <- lapply(my.tags, (function(tag){
  pat <-  paste("\\(", tag, "\\)\\.", sep="")
  pos <- regexpr(paste("(^|\\.)([[:alnum:]])*", pat ,sep=""), aa)
  out <- substr(aa, pos, (pos+attributes(pos)$match.length - 4 - length(tag)))  
  gsub("(^\\.)", "", out) 
}))
names(extr.data) <- my.tags
extr.data
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the functions (G...) are variable and the inputs are variable.  This does assume that your functions start with a G and your input is always a letter.

```
parse = function(arb){
  tmp = stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(arb,"G.*?\\([A-Z]\\)")[[1]]
  unlist(lapply(lapply(tmp,strsplit,"\\)|\\("),function(x){
    output = x[[1]][1]
    names(output) = x[[1]][2]
    return(output)
  }))
}
```

This first parses out all the G functions with their inputs.  Then, each of those is split into their function part and their input part.  This is the put into a character vector of functions named for their input.

```
parse("G30(H).G3(M).G0(L).Replicate(1)")
>     H     M     L 
  "G30"  "G3"  "G0"
```

Or

```
parse("G35(L).G31(P).G02(K).Replicate(1)")
>     L     P     K 
  "G35" "G31" "G02"
```